# Jquery uncheck RadioButtonList on TextBox change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a RadioButtonList inside a repeater and I want to clear the checked value on the OnChange of a textbox

```
<asp:Repeater ID="QuestionsRpt" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div class="form-horizontal form-condensed">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class='col-sm-6 control-label' style="text-align:left"><span id="Question" runat="server"><%# Eval("Name_" + UserLanguage.ToUpper()) %></span> <i class="fa fa-question-circle" runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("Description_" + UserLanguage.ToUpper()).ToString() != ""%>' data-toggle="tooltip" title='<%# Eval("Description_" + UserLanguage.ToUpper()).ToString()%>'></i></label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" CssClass="RadioButtonList" AutoPostBack="true"
                DataSource='<%# (Eval("ListOfChoice_" + UserLanguage.ToUpper()).ToString()).Split(";".ToCharArray()) %>'
                Visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Type_IsSingleChoice")) == 1)%>'>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

            <input type='text' id="OtherOptionTB" runat="server"
                placeholder='<%# GetLocalResourceObject("Other Option") %>' class="form-control otherOption input-sm" value=''                                    
                autocomplete="off" visible='<%# Eval("AllowFreeText")%>' onchange="ResetRadioButtonList()"/>

        </div>                                             
    </div>                            
    <br />
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>                            
    </div>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ResetRadioButtonList() {
    $(event.target).closest('.form-group').find('.RadioButtonList').prop('checked', false);
}
```

When I log $(event.target).closest('.form-group').find('.RadioButtonList') I do get the the RadioButtonList but I can't seem to figure out how to clear it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... 
I need to access all the inputs in my RadioButtonList

Here is the updated Jquery:

```
function ResetRadioButtonList() {
$(event.target).closest('.form-group').find('.RadioButtonList').find('input:radio').prop('checked', false);}
```